# Action Filter Attribute doesn't run

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this filter that I am trying to run

```
public class ModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
    }
}
```

I have placed it above my post controller like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Save")]
[ModelValidation]
public ActionResult Save(CreateUserDto Input)
{
    CreateUserViewModel cuvm = new CreateUserViewModel
    {
        Id = Input.Id,
        UserName = Input.UserName,
        Email = Input.Email,
        FirstName = Input.FirstName,
        LastName = Input.LastName,
        DateOfBirth = Input.DateOfBirth,
        PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
        Password = Input.Password,
        ConfirmPassword = Input.ConfirmPassword,
        RoleList = Input.RoleList,
        CreatedOn = Input.CreatedOn,
        UpdatedOn = Input.UpdatedOn
    };
    //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
    //    return BadRequest(Input);
    //}
    var result = applicationUsersData.Save(cuvm);
    if (Input.RoleList != null)
    {
        var RoleList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserAddRoleDetailsViewModel>>(Input.RoleList);
        foreach (var item in RoleList)
        {
            var uardvm = new SaveUserRolesDetailsViewModel
            {
                RoleId = item.Id,
                Id = result.Id
            };
            userRolesData.Save(uardvm);
        }
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

However, the filter doesn't trigger at all. How can I ensure that it runs? I have tried registering it in Startup.cs but that did not work as well.

EDIT: Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesFilter(RoleGlobals.SystemAdministrator, ApplicationGlobals.ApplicationName)));
});
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new ModelValidationAttribute());
});
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @davidfowl yeah I did. Thats why I'm using this filter attribute

Comment: Did you try running the filter sample https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/controllers/filters/sample and comparing it to your application?

Comment: Yes I just did. It ends up with a 401 unauthorized instead of my not found error

Comment: Authorize attributes run before action filters. If you have an authorize attribute on your controller it will run before your action filters.

Comment: I've added my startup.cs. It still doesn't get intercepted. I have tried to debug it and it doesn't run

Comment: Do you have an AuthorizeAttribute on your controller?

Comment: @davidfowl yes I do. Sorry I'm quite confused. Do I put this filter before the authorize attribute?

Comment: Take a look at the diagram for the filter pipeline. There are various stages to it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-types.

AuthorizationFilters run before ActionFilters. You're getting a 401 because it's running first (that's by design).

Comment: Sorry, I just realized why I was getting the 401 errors. When I added the filter to Startup.cs, for some reason it was blocking my token from being generated so I couldnt be authorized. But when I removed it, I can now be authorized but the filter is disabled.

Comment: So everything is fine now?

Comment: @davidfowl No, I need to register my action attribute/filter without it disabling my authorization filter. Im not sure how to do that

Comment: @JianYA You don't. The user first needs to go through the authorization filter, if that's successful then they'll get to your Action Filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Action Filter does not run if modelstate is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688257/action-filter-does-not-run-if-modelstate-is-not-valid)

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to implement `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute` and not `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: `System.Web` => ASP.NET Framework, NOT ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;