# Action Filter does not run if modelstate is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a custom action filter that is supposed to intercept the modelstate and do something depending on the current state (valid or invalid). However, after doing some checks, I realized that the action filter only runs if the modelstate is already valid ie. If all the entries of an input viewmodel are present.

An example is my authentication json. It has username,password and secret key.

```
{
    "Email": "user@apppp.com",
    "Password": "password",
    "SecretKey":""
}
```

The one above is modelstate invalid because secret key is required. Thus the action filter does not run

```
{
    "Email": "user@apppp.com",
    "Password": "password",
    "SecretKey":"abc"
}
```

This second one is modelstate valid thus the action filter runs. However, what I want to do is trigger my action filter even if its invalid. How can I overwrite that?

ActionFilter

```
public class ModelValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //context.Result = new ValidationFailedResult(context.ModelState);
            context.Result = new OkObjectResult("Hello");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new OkObjectResult("Bye");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running ASP.NET Core 2.1 with `[ApiController]` attribute on your controller? If yes, it will automatically add validation filter to all its actions. Consult the [ASP.NET Core 2.1 Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute). Can be disabled via `ApiBehaviorOptions`. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! This was what i needed exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Action Filter Attribute doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680343/action-filter-attribute-doesnt-run)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute) comes with an `[ApiController]` attribute which is used in the default templates and will add model validation to all actions of the given controller.

It can be disabled globally via `ApiBehaviorOptions` during Startup:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```